# Mystery template loading

Tags: templates

A brand new EE 2.9 installation and it is NOT loading the updated version of a template. The template is called "index", lives in a "home" group and is set to be the Site Homepage

The Template manager shows the new version, the file on the server shows the new version, the website shows the old version.

If I go to "example.com" it shows the old version.
If I go to "example.com/index" it shows the new version.

If I create NEW group with a NEW template as the homepage it STILL loads the original old "index" template from "home" group.

I have: Cleared all EE caches, ensured template caching is turned of, cleared all browser caches, tested on Firefox, Chrome and IE.

WTF?

**Update:** Deleted template files from server and Template Group from EE and IT STILL shows the old template! Checked the "exp_templates" table and it shows NO templates.

Comment: Just noticed that directory permissions are 777 instead of 755 (cPanel/WHM server). Every time I change them to 755 and then perform a Template Sync the permissions change back to 777. ???

Comment: Answered my own question. Root Cause: Stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove index.html from document root of webserver. I had stupidly left a a sample file and forgot about it.